# OpenNLP NameFinder training, "Found unexpected annotation"

Tags: opennlp, named-entity-recognition, training-data

In training my NameFinderME, I get the following error message:

My data looks as follows:
`<START someTag> some text <END>`

`Computing event counts...  java.io.IOException: Found unexpected annotation:`

In everything else Google has found me for this error message, it's always a simple error in the spacing of the training data (e.g., change `<START:entity>some text<END>` to  `<START:entity> some text <END>` .  This isn't applicable to me (it's all correctly spaced.)  It's all UTF-16, and specified to be so when I set up the objects to do the training.  Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Thank you,

WalrusTheCat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data is incorrect.  Instead of `<START someTag>` I need `<START:someTag>`.  I was using a space instead of a colon.

Comment: Hi, i am also getting the same exception although i am writing sentences like this. <START:person> Rahul Vashishth <END> , 61 years old. Any guess ?

Comment: the only thing i would suggest is finding example training data out there that works and finding out exactly how it differs from yours.  the two cases i've identified in this question are that of not using a space between the tags and tokens, and using a space instead of a colon inside the tag, but there are probably others.

Answer (score 0):

Also, when occurring problem like this, please be sure your  and  tags are surrounded by a space, so instead of `Next person, <START:person>Rahul Vashishth<END>, is 61 years old.` use `Next person, <START:person> Rahul Vashishth <END>, is 61 years old.`